# Unable to import Loader modules with Python

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, loadui

I am a beginner with python and started using Eclipse very recently. I am using Qt-designer and created a file named MyWidget.ui, but while running the program I receive an error:

> from PyQt4.uic.Loader.loader import DynamicUILoader
>   ImportError: No module named Loader.loader

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic

class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('MyWidget.ui', self)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MyWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What platform are you on? Are you sure you've installed all the necessary pyqt packages? With some minor corrections, the above example script works as expected for me.

Answer (score 1):

1 Design a user interface in QT4 Designer. Save as a .ui file (XML).

2 Generate Python code from the UI file using pyuic.

pyuic4.bat -x myForm.ui > myForm.py  On Windows it's bat file
pyuic4 -x myForm.ui > myForm.py    On Linux it's a script

3 Test the UI. The '-x' option to pyuic causes it to emit a built-in test program so you can just run myForm.py from the command line to test it.

4 Create a python wrapper with the event loop in it. For example, this is similar to what the '-x' option gives you.

Answer (score 0):

Put an empty
`__init__.py`
file in the '\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\Loader' sub-directory.